# Perl printing set from another set

Tags: perl

I have this script which pretty much just prints a data set from vertical to horizontal.

I was it to skip over some names where are not part of the set that I want. 
Howerver I want to print out just select Initials, while retaining the orders.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper ;

my $filename = shift @ARGV ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";
while (<$fh>) {
        next if /^$/;
        chomp $_ ;
        print $_ ;
}
```

Pseudocode

```
if $_ (is one of these WJ: DS: AP: ) 
   print $_
   else 
   skip, don't print
```

So from this set -

```
LC:
NW:
DS:
AP:
II:
NW:
KB:
JK:
LC:
DS:
TM:
AP: 
WJ:
```

These would NOT get printed to terminal

```
LC:
NW:
II:
NW:
KB:
JK:
TM:
```

These would get printed to terminal - horizontally with order retained

```
DS: AP: AP: WJ:
```

Comment: you could try `print if /(?:WJ|DS|AP):/`

Answer (score 2):

```
next if !/^(?:AP|DS|WJ):\z/;
```

---

What if we didn't want to hardcode the list.

Prep:

```
my @to_keep = qw( AP DS WJ );
my $to_keep_alt = join '|', map quotemeta, @to_keep;
my $to_keep_re = qr/^(?:$to_keep_alt):\z/;
```

In loop:

```
next if !/$to_keep_re/;
```

---

A faster way alternative that doesn't require hardcoding the list.

Prep:

```
my @to_keep = qw( AP DS WJ );
my %to_keep = map { "$_:" => 1 } @to_keep;
```

In loop:

```
next if !$to_keep{$_};
```

Comment: Had it negated. Fixed.